# Run two codes simultaneously c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I have this situation in an app I am developing where I need to do two things at exactly the same time and I am kind of struggling with it. I am developing a camera application and I need to trigger the camera at the same time as an LED in order to get a good image. The following are the options I have tried.

1. Use two threads:

   ```
   Thread t1 = new Thread(
                       new ThreadStart(() =>
                       {
                           //trigger LED here
                       }));

   Thread t2 = new Thread(
                       new ThreadStart(() =>
                       {
                           //trigger camera
                       }));

   t1.Start();

   t2.Start();
   t1.Join();
   t2.Join();
   ```
2. Trigger the light on the current thread and the camera on a separate thread

   ```
   Thread t = new Thread(
                       new ThreadStart(() =>
                       {
                           //trigger camera
                       }));

   // trigger LED
   t.Start();
   t.Join();
   ```

In both cases, I get the back flickers after like 10 images which means the camera and LED are not synchronised. My question is, is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no hardware interface method to do both at the same time? I assume you're using an API to talk to the hardware?

Comment: as mention ,you need to read the API your hardware/stack is providing. Hight possibility that there is API to activate both

Comment: I can't see two threads being better - even if you manage to get them running at the same time on two different processor cores (which I suspect is unlikely and, in any event, impossible to control), they'll clash accessing the hardware bus and you'll end up with sequential activation. I imagine simply activating one after the other in the same thread would be better (or do the calls block until the activity is complete? Is there an async version of the call, if so?).

Comment: @Matthew, Mzf: Hi, the camera and LED are two different hardware. I trigger the LED through a serial call and the camera directly from its API.

Comment: @BobSammers; thanks for your post. The calls doesn't block the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't solve this in hardware here is the best approach that I can think of on a non-realtime OS like Windows:

1. Start one thread for each of the two actions
2. Raise their priorities to High or Realtime to ensure that they immediately kick anything else off the CPU
3. Make them wait on a [`Barrier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.barrier.aspx). This ensures that both threads have started and checked in at the barrier before continuing. This helps to reduce timing jitter. It does not guarantee that both threads execute their hardware action at the same time but it will help.

If that does not help I don't know what would. It is worth a try though. The OS does not guarantee realtime execution but with CPU speeds north of 3 GHZ you can achieve amazing realtime speeds. **A context switch might take 3000 cycles which is 0.000001 seconds.** So you absolutely can achieve extremely accurate timings.

Comment: Wow! This works like a charm. I believe that is exactly what Barrier is for: not necessary to raise the priority I think (but in some other cases maybe but I am looking at the performance hit of 3 real time processes on the computer but in my  case normal priority is fine enough). The program has been running for 30 mins now (around 1500 frames and no blinking). I am actually synchronising 2 camera with 1 LED and this solution works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two (or more) actions, you can invoke them in parallel using

```
Parallel.Invoke( () => DoCamera(), () => DoLighting() );
```

However, that's a best try. There's no guarantee because after all you might execute this on a machine with only one physical processor or maybe it's under heavy load and only has 10% CPU left anyway.

Comment: @nvoigt: then why offer it as a solution? It doesn't do anything the OP's example doesn't do (although it is neater) and he's already stated that doesn't work.

Comment: Because it's the best he can get, there is no guarantee in the whole .NET Framework. No piece of software can guarantee parallelism on a machine that isn't even guaranteed to have two processors.

Comment: I disagree - the best he can do is change the thread priority as Bernhard Hofmann suggests and, providing they don't block whilst the activity is taking place, run the two calls in the same thread

Answer (score 2):

How are you controlling the two devices (USB)? You might have two physical CPUs that are able to perform the operations at the same time, but if your interface(s) need the same communication channels, you will find a delay.

Also, you might want to increase the priority of your threads if they are time critical.

If you want the threads synchronised, you should use some form of thread synchronisation such as a mutex, but unless you can guarantee that you (and your customers) have two CPUs, you might be better off performing the two operations in a critical section whilst setting your thread to time critical. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077501/c-sharp-how-to-maximize-chance-that-particular-section-of-code-will-have-no-cont) for details on that.

Comment: Hi Bernhard, thank you for your post. The camera is USB while the LED is a serial device. I'll try the priority thing and report back here.

Answer (score 0):

What you are effectively asking for is a tight coupling between the hardware (camera trigger and LED) and the programming framework to achieve a "real-time" OS.  Windows is not a real-time operating system - Microsoft's goal was to develop a platform that is mostly agnostic to the hardware it is running on.

Even for threads - once you ask the CLR to spin up a thread, there is *no guarantee* that the thread will start running within a specified time interval (reference [CLR via C#](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0790145353665.do)).